# Warning about TF to MSG

Tags: ros, viso2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run viso2 mono_odometer I get warnings like

TF to MSG: Quaternion Not Properly Normalized.

I find no translation happens when I move the camera tf are all zeros. Is that because of this warning, which prevent the node to publish tf to odom itself?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65331/warning-about-tf-to-msg/) by [Jia](https://answers.ros.org/users/5160/jia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-06-17**:
Please at least copy and paste the warnings so we can help you.  [www.ros.org/wiki/Support](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support) Also specific instructions about how to reproduce your problem would be helpful.

**Comment by [Jia](https://answers.ros.org/users/5160/jia/) on 2013-06-17**:
sry, I did paste the warning but it didn't show. Now it should be fine.

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2013-06-30**:
Hi Jia! Can you show the last pose messages before that warning?

**Comment by [pvfloripa](https://answers.ros.org/users/5321/pvfloripa/) on 2013-07-04**:
Hi Jia, did you find an answer for this issue? I am having the same problem, even though my system does not present any of the direct limitations of viso2_ros (ie, it is moving forward, contains a ground plane, etc). Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With a deep investigation into the source code of viso2, my colleague and I finally solved this issue by calling a service called resetPose. So basically, as soon as the node mono_odometer has been brought up, open a new terminal and type "rosservice call /mono_odometer/reset_pose". For more information, please refer to the reset_pose service callback function which is in odometer_pose.h file. Hope this answer will help those who have the same issue as stated above.

---

Originally posted by [chenling34401](https://answers.ros.org/users/2274/chenling34401/) with karma: 36 on 2013-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A quaternion must have the sum of the squares of all 4 values add up to 1.  Make sure you are setting a valid quaternion.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-06-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1